# What are the rules that govern the attribute given to someone as a result of where they come from?

Tags: demonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any rules governing what we call people from different countries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/are-there-any-rules-governing-what-we-call-people-from-different-countries)

For example someone from London might be said to be a Londoner. However someone from America [United States] is referred to as American. Other examples [both on a wide and more local geographical scale]:

New York: New Yorker.

Scotland: Scottish

Kent: Kentish [Kentish Men?]

Germany: German

Eton: Etonian [Having been to Eton College]

What I am asking is what grammatical rules govern the suffix that gets attached to the place derived names? They 'sound right' to me but that may be that I have heard them so ofter I am used to them. If I met someone who came from a town, county or country I had never heard of how would I go about deciding that he/she was a ....er, or ....ian, or ...ish?

Londoner sounds OK for use in this way but Londonish and Londinian do not [to me at least]

I hope I have made my query clear. I would be grateful to hear the opinion of others.

Comment: Tasmania -> Taswegian, Glasgow -> Glaswegian

Comment: Rules? Conventions, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

There really aren't any rules. As near as I can tell people just try out a few terms, and keep the ones they like.

There do appear to be some guidelines. Generally, people seem to start by adding `er`, `ite`, or `an` to the end of their place name, and sticking with the better-sounding ones.

Some can get really outlandish though. When I was living in New Orleans, people who were native there were often referred to as "dats", probably from [Who Dat?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Dat?)