# When to use -Ites / Ians / Ish / An / Ni / Ese / Elsh / Er

Tags: pronunciation, slang, suffixes, demonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any rules governing what we call people from different countries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/are-there-any-rules-governing-what-we-call-people-from-different-countries)

I have some confusion regarding usage of suffixes such as *-ites* / *-ians* / *-ish*.

For example:

I have seen some people using the words Kerel*ite* and Mumba*ites* for people from Kerela (a state) and Mumbai (a city).

Other examples:

- Ind*ians* (where India is a country)
- Span*ish* (Where Spain is again a country)
- Americ*an*
- Pakista*ni*
- Chin*ese*
- W*elsh*
- New York*er*

So on what basis do we decide what suffixes should be used, or is it very dependent on mood or environment?

Comment: Your link doesn't give any answer for usage of -ites

Comment: You also forgot *-er,* as in *New Yorker*.

Comment: Don't forget *-elsh*, as in *Welsh*, *-ine* as in *Florentine*, *-e(n)o* as in * Los Angeleno* and *Filipino*, *-ene* as in *Damascene*, *-ensian* as in *Hullensian*, *-ard* as in *Spaniard*,  *-ic* as in *Hispanic*, *iot(e)* as in *Cypriot* and *Phanariote*, *-asque* as in *Monégasque*, *-gian* as in *Glaswegian*, *-onian* as in *Dundonian* and *-vian* as in *Krakovian*. By the way, these are all **[demonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#Suffixation)**, "a name for a resident of a locality".

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, by adding things in the list, it will help some find for such suffixes at one place.

Comment: @linuxeasy Because you basically have to learn each one, rather than us mimicking Wikipedia, you're best off checking the [Wikipedia demonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#Suffixation) page each time you're unsure. We don't want this site to become a Wikipedia mirror.

Comment: Eh my comment got deleted! I had linked to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#Suffixation and to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_forms_of_place_names

Comment: See also [Are there any universal rules in appropriating -an, -sh, -es, -ch, for -th?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197807/are-there-any-universal-rules-in-appropriating-an-sh-es-ch-for-th)

Answer (score 8):

It’s not a matter of mood or environment, since you can’t change these endings at will. Foreign learners have to learn each one as they encounter them. Whether a citizen of a country and the adjective derived from the countrty's name end in *–ish* or *–(i)an* (or something else) may be largely a matter of historical accident. It may be relevant that the *–ish* suffix has a Germanic origin, the *–(i)an* one a Latin one.