# Are there any universal rules in appropriating “_an,” “_sh,” “_es,” “_ch” for the demonyms of countries?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, demonyms

Suffixes indicating people and language of country vary by country:

_an: American, German, Italian, Belgian, Australian, Russian, Ukrainian, Korean,  Mexican, Brazilian, Chilean, Argentinean, Indonesian, Malaysian, Iranian, Egyptian, Somalian, Palestinian

_sh: English, British, Polish, Danish, Swedish, Turkish,

_ch: French, Dutch

_ese: Chinese, Taiwanese, Japanese, Vietnamese, Portuguese

_no: Filipino, Latino

_i: Israeli

_: Thai

Among the above, _an seems to outnumber other suffixes.

Are there any simple rule to govern appropriation of suffix turning a country name into adjective, indicating people and language of countries in the world in terms of say, region, race, or cultural background? Or is it just discretional?

Comment: And don't forget the -i ending: Iraqi, Azerbaijani, Pakistani, Israeli, Kuwaiti, Saudi, etc.

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/61765/8019).

Comment: It is very nearly the same question, but that question drew only one answer, and that answer didn't offer any theory as to why the suffixes that attach to the various country names do so—which is the core question here. Maybe someone can do better this time. The concentrations of -ese endings in the Far East and of -i endings in the Middle East, while not exclusive to those area, do suggest that something more than random suffix attaching is going on.

Comment: Here are some interesting hints:http://ask.metafilter.com/104529/Rules-for-converting-country-names-to-adjectival-form

Comment: One rule of thumb: Countries ending in-a or -ia tend top have the adjective -an or -ian.

Comment: @Mitch. Sounds reasonable, except for China.

Comment: Note that the link highlighted in the "Possible Duplicate" notice at the top of the question is itself listed as a duplicate of [Are There Any Rules Governing What We Call People From Different Countries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/are-there-any-rules-governing-what-we-call-people-from-different-countries) So now we have four versions of the same question: Yoichi Oishi's question, the question that Tim Lymington links to, the question that the Possible Duplicate notice links to, and the one I linked to here—each with different answers. Is it time to consolidate answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Identifying the Relevant English Suffixes***

First, let’s consider the English suffixes that are most commonly used to create adjectival forms of country names, and the situations in which they arise. The following distinctive forms struck me as being especially prevalent: *-ian* as an adjectival suffix in situations where the country name ends in *-ia*; *-ian* as an adjectival suffix in situations where the country name does not end in –ia; *-n* as an adjectival suffix in situations where the country name ends in *-a* (but not in *-ia*); *-an* as an adjectival suffix for country names not ending in *-a*; *-ese* as an adjectival suffix; *-i* as an adjectival suffix; *-ic* as an adjectival suffix; *-ish* as an adjectival suffix in situations where the country name ends in *-land*;  *-ish* as an adjectival suffix in situations where the country name ends in something other than *-land*; and situations where the adjectival form of the country name is a truncation of the country name. There are also some special cases that don’t follow any recognizable pattern.

Various reference works have analyzed the suffixes involved. Here is what Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (2002) has to say about each of the relevant suffixes:

> **-ese** *Forming adjectives and nouns.* [Old French *-eis*, based on Latin *-ensis*.]
>
> Adjectives denote an inhabitant or language of a city or country: ***Cantonese***, ***Japanese***, ***Maltese***, ***Nepalese***, ***Taiwanese***, ***Vietnamese***, ***Viennese***.
>
> ...
>
> **-i** *Adjectives and nouns relating to countries* [Semitic and Indo-Iranian adjectival endings.]
>
> The countries are in the Near or Middle East or South Asia, and the forms can either be adjectives relating to the country, or nouns for a native or national of the country: ***Azeri***, ***Azerbaijani***, ***Bangladeshi***, ***Hindi***, ***Israeli***, ***Kuwaiti***, ***Nepali***, ***Pakistani***.
>
> ...
>
> **-ian** Also **-an**. *Forming adjectives and nouns.* [Latin adjectival endings *-anus*, *-ana*, *-anum*, ‘of or belonging to something’.]
>
> The original form was **-an**, as in ***urban*** [etymology omitted] and ***Roman*** [etymology omitted]. However, many Latin words had an *i* before the ending [example omitted] and other examples ending in **-ian** come from French words ending in *-ien* [example omitted] that are derived from Latin. As a result, the usual form is now **-ian**, though it is truncated to **-an** if the stem ends in a vowel.
>
> One set is of adjectives that refer to places: ***Australian***, ***Chicagoan***, ***Indian***, ***Kenyan***, ***Malayan***, ***Nebraskan***, ***Parisian***, ***Puerto Rican***, ***Scandinavian***, ***Tibetan***, and so on. Some modify the stem: ***Glaswegian***, ***Norwegian***, ***Peruvian***. Most can also be nouns that identify a person from the place.
>
> ...
>
> **-ic** *Forming adjectives and some nouns.* [French *-ique*, Latin *-icus*, or Greek *-ikos*.]
>
> ...
>
> **-ish** *Forming adjectives.* [Old English *-isc*, of Germanic origin; related to Old Norse *-iskr*, German and Dutch *-isch*, also to Greek *-iskos* (a suffix forming diminutive nouns).]
>
> This suffix forms adjectives from nouns and from other adjectives.
>
> One set from nouns is of adjectives for a member of a nation (***British***, ***Cornish***, ***Irish***, ***Netherlandish***, ***Polish***, ***Swedish***, ***Turkish***), occasionally of a religious or other group, as with ***Jewish***. Rarely, the ending has been reduced to *-sh*, as in ***Welsh***.

To sum up, the sources of the suffixes used to create the adjectival forms of most country names in English are Old French (*-ese*), Semitic and Indo-Iranian (*-i*), Latin (*-ian* and *-an*), French (*-ic*), and Old English (*-ish*). That’s quite a smorgasbord.

---

***Sorting the Adjectives into Nonoverlapping Categories***

Before doing any research into the relevant suffixes, I tried to sort a bunch of adjectives (172 of them, altogether) derived from past or current country, continent, or region names into coherent categories. I ended up with ten distinct categories, plus one catch-all category for unique oddball adjectives. (Note that the adjectival forms given here are descriptive adjectives for the place, which may not match the word used for the people or language associated with the place name.)

**Place names ending in *-ia* that take the adjectival form *-ian* (40):**

Albania, Albanian; Algeria, Algerian; Arabia, Arabian [or Arab or Arabic]; Armenia, Armenian; Austria, Austrian; Australia, Australian; Asia, Asian; Bolivia, Bolivian; Bosnia, Bosnian; Bulgaria, Bulgarian [or Bulgar]; Cambodia, Cambodian; Catalonia, Catalonian [or Catalan]; Colombia, Colombian; Czechoslovakia, Czechoslovakian [or Czech]; Croatia, Croatian; Estonia, Estonian; Ethiopia, Ethiopia; Georgia, Georgian; India, Indian; Indonesia, Indonesian; Latvia, Latvian; Liberia, Liberian; Lithuania, Lithuanian; Macedonia, Macedonian; Malaysia, Malaysian; Mauritania, Mauritanian; Mongolia, Mongolian; Namibia, Namibian; Nigeria, Nigerian; Prussia, Prussian; Romania, Romanian; Russia, Russian; Serbia, Serbian
Slovakia, Slovakian; Slovenia, Slovenian; Somalia, Somalian [or Somali]; Syria, Syrian; Tanzania, Tanzanian; Tunisia, Tunisian; Zambia, Zambian

**Place names ending in something other than *-ia* but taking the adjectival form *-ian*, sometimes with additional alterations (26):**

Alsace, Alsatian; Argentina, Argentinian [or Argentine]; Babylon, Babylonian; Bahamas, Bahamian; Belgium, Belgian; Brazil, Brazilian; Burgundy, Burgundian; Cameroon, Cameroonian; Canada, Canadian; Chad, Chadian; Ecuador, Ecuadorian; Egypt, Egyptian; Ghana, Ghanaian [or Ghanian or Ghanese]; Herzegovina, Herzegovinian; Hungary, Hungarian; Iran, Iranian; Italy, Italian; Ivory Coast, Ivorian
Jordan, Jordanian; Laos, Laotian [or Lao]; Luxembourg, Luxembourgian; Norway, Norwegian; Palestine, Palestinian; Peru, Peruvian; Sicily, Sicilian; Ukraine, Ukrainian

**Place names ending in *-a* (but not in *-ia*) that take the suffix *-n* (21):**

Africa, African; America, American; Angola, Angolan; Botswana, Botswanan; Costa Rica, Costa Rican; Cuba, Cuban; Dahomey, Dahomeyan; Eritrea, Eritrean; Guatemala, Guatemalan; Guinea, Guinean; Jamaica, Jamaican; Kenya, Kenyan; Korea, Korean; Libya, Libyan; Moldova, Moldovan; Rwanda, Rwandan [or Rwandese]; Sahara, Saharan; Sri Lanka, Sri Lankan; Uganda, Ugandan; Upper Volta, Upper Voltan; Venezuela, Venezuelan

**Place names not ending in *-a* that take the suffix *-an*, sometimes with other alterations (21 + 1 exception):**

Brunei, Bruneian; Burundi, Burundian; Chile, Chilean; Djibouti, Djiboutian; Ecuador, Ecuadoran [or Ecuadorean or Ecuadorian]; Europe, European; Haiti, Haitian; Madagascar, Madagascan; Malawi, Malawian; Mali, Malian; Mexico, Mexican; Morocco, Moroccan; Mozambique, Mozambican; Paraguay, Paraguayan; Puerto Rico, Puerto Rican; Sierra Leone, Sierra Leonean; Singapore, Singaporean; Tibet, Tibetan; Uruguay, Uruguayan; Zaire, Zairean [or Zairian]; Zimbabwe, Zimbabwean

[Exception: Montenegro, Montenegrin]

**Place names that take the suffix *-ese*, sometimes with other alterations (20):**

Burma, Burmese; Ceylon, Ceylonese; China, Chinese; Benin, Beninese; Bhutan, Bhutanese; Congo, Congolese; Faroe Islands, Faroese; Gabon, Gabonese; Guyana, Guyanese; Japan, Japanese; Lebanon, Lebanese; Nepal, Nepalese; Portugal, Portuguese; Siam, Siamese; Senegal, Senegalese; Sudan, Sudanese; Suriname, Surinamese; Taiwan, Taiwanese; Togo, Togolese; Vietnam, Vietnamese

**Place names that take the suffix *-i* (8):**

Bangladesh, Bangladeshi; Iraq, Iraqi; Israel, Israeli; Kuwait, Kuwaiti; Oman, Omani; Pakistan, Pakistani; Qatar, Qatari; Yemen, Yemeni

**Place names ending in *-land* that take the suffix  *-ish*, sometimes with final consonant doubling (5):**

England, English; Finland, Finnish; Ireland, Irish; Poland, Polish; Scotland, Scottish

**Place names ending in *-land* that take the suffix *-ic* (2):**

Greenland, Greenlandic; Iceland, Icelandic

**Other place names ending in *-ish*, sometimes with other alterations (7):**

Flanders, Flemish; Kurdistan, Kurdish; Spain, Spanish; Sweden, Swedish; Denmark, Danish; Turkey, Turkish; Wales, Welsh

**Place names with truncated, and sometimes further altered,
adjectival forms (14):**

Afghanistan, Afghan; Germany, German; Kazakhstan, Kazakh [or Kazakhstani]; Kyrgyzstan, Kyrgyz; Lapland, Lapp; Myanmar, Myanma; Netherlands, Netherland [or Netherlandic or Netherlandish]; Philippines, Philippine; Saxony, Saxon; Switzerland, Swiss; Tajikistan, Tajik; Thailand, Thai; Turkmenistan, Turkmen [or Turkmenian]; Uzbekistan, Uzbek [or Uzbeki or Uzbekistani]

**Special cases (7):**

Burkina Faso, Burkinabe; France, French; Cyprus, Cypriot; Greece, Greek; Isle of Mann, Manx; Niger, Nigerois; Holland, Dutch

---

***Assessing the Results***

When you look at the entries closely, you quickly see that even some members of a relatively well-ordered group may be unpredictable. For example, according to Quinion, the *-an* family consists of adjectives whose *-ian* ending is “truncated to *-an* [because] the stem ends in a vowel.” But how then do we explain *Ecuadoran*, *Madagascan*, and *Tibetan*? And why is the adjectival form of *Montenegro* (in Merriam-Webster, anyway) *Montenegrin* instead of *Montenegran*?

Likewise I can’t see any compelling reason why *Africa*, a three-syllable word ending in *a* and with the stress on the first syllable, took the adjectival form *African*, while *Canada*, a three-syllable word ending in *a* and with the stress on the first syllable, took the adjectival form *Canadian*.

For a more advanced challenge, see if you can explain why *England* yields *English*, *Finland* yields *Finnish*, *Iceland* yields *Icelandic*, *Switzerland* yields *Swiss*, and *Holland* yields *Dutch*. Given that record of inconsistency, I have no idea what the preferred adjectival form for *Falkland Islands* is—*Falklish*? *Falklandic*? *Falk*? *Falklandese*? The answer certainly isn’t intuitively obvious from the disparate forms that other *-land*-based adjectives have taken.

Another important point involves the vastly different eras when different adjectival forms were created. England’s oldest and nearest neighbors (and England itself) get the Old English–derived *-ish* treatment. In sharp contrast, the various Middle East and South Asian states that gained independence after World War II are the likeliest to have acquired the Semitic and Indo-Iranian suffix *-i*. An extreme example from the “Special cases” category is *Burkinabe*, the approved adjectival form of *Burkina Faso*, a country whose new name (supplanting *Upper Volta*) is itself only 30 years old. The *-be* suffix in  *Burkinabe* is presumably drawn from an indigenous language, as indeed *Burkina* is (*Faso* is from the nation’s other major language, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burkina_Faso)); but it’s hard to imagine the foreign office in Britain or the United States a century ago showing much solicitude for the preferences of colonial populations—their own or any other country’s—in the framing of place-name adjectives.

A further complication involves inconsistent adjective assignments through the years. In its entry for the adjective *Chinese*, for example, the full-size OED notes that “In 16th c., **Chinish** was used.”

Simple practicality explains why one member of the oddball category has an unusual suffix. *Nigerois*, the adjectival form of *Niger*, exists simply because the obvious choice, *Nigerian*, was already taken by *Nigeria*. We’re unlikely to see any other place-name adjectives with *-ois* endings (except perhaps *Quebecois*) unless a similar conflict over rights to the obvious English word arises.

Ultimately, there are far too many variations in the adjectival forms of place names with similar endings in English to permit any universal and systematic explanation for the endings actually chosen. Nevertheless certain patterns are evident in certain places or with certain endings—and most English adjectives based on country names at least have similar (and similarly derived) words to keep them company.

Comment: Many Middle Eastern and Caucasus peoples not well-known to the English world for more than a century or so take that "-i" ending . . . Kuwaiti, Uzbeki, Israeli, Iraqi, Saudi. (But more historically 'recognized' peoples like the Egyptians or the Turks follow more "Euro" models. It's interesting to see some people described with both forms: "Kurdish" and "Kurdi" both seem to be used frequently.)

Comment: @Sven Yargs. Do you have any idea about predominance of "_an, _ian" over other suffixes?

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: I am trying to assemble a list of country names and related adjective forms that may at least identify the usual channels that such names run into in English. But I also want to consult various reference works to see whether they have any insights into the different meanings (if they are different) of the various relevant suffixes. I will update my answer here if I find anything of interest.

Comment: One small comment: the country _Holland_ does not exist. It's a nickname for _The Netherlands_. The demonym is still irregular though.

Comment: Hi, oerkelens. I included a number of obsolete/inaccurate country names in my list (_Siam_, _Ceylon_, and _Dahomey_ are other examples) because in the past they were commonly used in English to designate those nations/states/regions. I included _Holland_ for that reason and because _Holland/Dutch_ doesn't follow any of the patterns that most of the other adjectival forms fall into. I might have made the same argument about _Netherlands/Dutch_, but it's less clear-cut because _Netherlandish_ is also available. I doubt that most English speakers ever used _Hollandaise_ except for the sauce.

Comment: _Netherlandish_ is actually in use? Then I haven't said anything (but I _am_ surprised!).

Comment: Well, that's what Michael Quinion says in his book (cited in my answer above); it's an Oxford University Press book published in the UK (OUP also has a major publishing wing in the U.S.), so I thought perhaps _Netherlandish_ was more common there. Meanwhile, Merriam-Webster gives three adjectival forms for _Netherlands_ (_Netherland_, _Netherlandic_, and _Netherlandish_) but none for _Holland_. Having said all that, I freely admit that I've never heard anyone use anything but _Dutch_ as the proper-name-based adjective associated with _Netherlands_.

Comment: @Sven Yergo. Thanks a lot. I’ve never seen such an elaborated, extensive and professional answer to a question since I’ve joined this site, which unfortunately wasn’t available in the previous questions with which my question was judged to “Duplicate.” I’m content with the fact that “Duplicated question” induced much detailed, thorough answer than the earlier ones.