# Why -stani and not -stanian?

Tags: adjectives

What is the reason for ending of adjectives that originate from countries ending with *-stan* being *-stani* and not *-stanian*?

Why "Iran" has "Iran**ian** rial" but "Kazakhstan" has "Kazakhstan**i** tenge"?

Are all adjectives have to be like that or is it sometimes grammatically correct to say "Kazakhstanian"?

Comment: Relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/197813/77227