# What's the origin of the demonym Thai?

Tags: etymology, morphology, derivational-morphology, demonyms, ethnonyms

I was curious why we called people from Thailand "Thai" and those from Taiwan "Taiwanese."
The latter by itself is a bit less surprising, though.

See also:
[Are there any rules governing what we call people from different countries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/are-there-any-rules-governing-what-we-call-people-from-different-countries)
and
[Is there a rule to what ending you use when you construct the nationality adjective? Or where did the various endings come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81649/is-there-a-rule-to-what-ending-you-use-when-you-construct-the-nationality-adject)
and
[Demonym on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym).

Comment: Thainese would surely be funnier.

Comment: Other European languages call them _thailandais_, _Thailender_ and so forth. English is thus being respectful and (I believe) calling them what they call themselves. In the period in which they migrated south from what is now Yunnan, namely the early 13th, I think you will find them spelt T'ai. Are you suggesting it's the same name as in Taiwan? You have any reason to think so? Coincidences exist: I have been in a Japanese town called Obama.

Comment: T'ai is a broader term that covers Lao, Shan, and Thai (according to the OED).
The connection I was making between Thailand and Taiwan - for the purpose of this question - was about the similar sound of the name (e.g. both 2 syllables, first syllable being the same), yet these two have very different demonyms.

Comment: @WBT: It seems like you already did some research. Can you please include in your question also? For example, [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thai) mentions that "Thai" is a native name and same as 'Tai' which literally means "free".

Comment: What research I've done is already on this page, except that I also checked Merriam-Webster for a derivation and didn't find one.  Your additional sources are new to me, consider adding them in an answer!

Comment: @WBT: I mean in the original post. Not in the comments. The more detailed question is, the better it is. Your question as it appears lacks research about the words you mentioned. I'm helping also. Etymonline was one of the commonly available references that you could check.

Comment: @WBT. My sense is that Thai and Taiwan are of entirely different etymologies. The latter sounds to me like a classic Chinese tonal double name *Tai Wan*, based on Chinese characters. But as you seem to know about Thailand, when did we stop calling it *Siam* and why?

Comment: People from Finland are also Finns, people from Scotland are Scots, people from Swaziland are Swazi, and people from Poland are Poles; though people from Ireland are not Ires, people from Holland are not Hols, people from Greenland are not Greens, and people from England are not Engs, though they used to be Angles. _-land_ is a productive way of naming, well, lands. _-wan_, on the other hand, is not a land-naming suffix at all, so a different, productive, strategy had to be employed there instead.

Comment: @Janus: You deploy some bad examples: Greenland was named before the place had any people living there. It was realtor-speak. Holland is properly speaking not the name of a country but a province thereof.

Comment: @DavidPugh I never said it was—but people from the Netherlands aren't called Nethers, either. My point was that you cannot compare a productive, transparent suffix to an intrinsic part of a foreign word and ask why one does not behave like the other.

Comment: @Janus: A busload of Nethers would be almost funny. What can we do with the Scilly Isles? I'm frustrated now, as I feel sure I've heard examples of people trying to treat the foreign-word part according to the rules of their own, but can't recall them for your delectation. I suppose a similar error is committed by those who think (confusing a heuristic trick with an etymology) that "history" is so-called _because_ it is the chronicle of men.

Answer (score 2):

WBT's answer is correct. The country is named after the people. Here's the Wikipedia reference for the Tai People (sic) tribe, to which the original Thai people originated from.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_peoples

And the official Thailand Wikipedia page mentions this under the Etymology section:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thailand

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's because the country is named for the people, rather than the other way around.

(This is from a secondary comment on the linked Wikipedia page).

Comment: It would be better to cite a source that backs up your assertion than to use the weasel word 'apparently' to justify it.

Comment: I didn't know Wikipedia counted for a reliable source around here.  "Apparently" is because I didn't vet that through independently, but I wanted to provide a starting point for what to possibly look for in writing a more reliable answer.

Comment: A Wikipedia article may or may or may not be reliable, depending on how judiciously the information it contains has been assessed, interpreted and curated. The list of references cited at the end of a Wikipedia entry is a good starting point for judging the quality of the article. In general, Wikipedia's peer review mechanism will rapidly eliminate inaccurate or questionable material in high-importance, high-visibility articles like those cited in @Ben Bearfish's answer.

Comment: @Erik: And in low-importance articles, ghod help us all. I use Wikipedia to improve a chronology of the 12th century I have created, and tendentious material is fairly rare there. But the number of links that go somewhere else entirely, and the number of articles that give deeds done by men who have been dead for years is astounding. (They do this in the _same_ article as gives his date of death.) No malice, just sloppiness. I would correct this sort of careless error myself except that I find the process intimidating, far worse than here; and no one else does.