# What is the proper demonym for someone from Shreveport?

Tags: suffixes, demonyms

[A tweet popped up in my feed recently](https://twitter.com/jakcadden/status/293728981100920832) that posed a really good question. On first blush I thought "Oh, I can answer this!" then upon further reflection I realized I can't.

In the case of "New Yorkers", we add "-er" to "New York". In the case of "Scandinavian", we add an "-n" to "Scandinavia". And so on.

So, to finally propose the question that was asked on Twitter:

> What is the proper demonym for someone from Shreveport?

I assume it's "Shreveporter" but that doesn't quite sound right.

I saw [this general discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/are-there-any-rules-governing-what-we-call-people-from-different-countries), but it doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: You'll have to ask somebody from Shreveport. Demonyms are intensely local and follow no general pattern.

Comment: People from Shrewsbury can't even agree on how to pronounce their town.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's always been known as *Shrowsbury* dating back to Saxon times. Just because a bunch of adolescent students on facebook fancy changing it to *Shroowsbury* doesn't make it so. There are many such anomalies in English town name pronunciations, try getting your average American to pronounce Leicestershire or Worcestershire correctly.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, quite so. Whilst the residents of Birmingham,Alabama are *Birminghamians*, those of *Birmingham, England* are *Brummies*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Going by](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ashreveportla.gov%20shreveporter) the official website of Shreveport, [shreveportla.gov](http://www.shreveportla.gov/), the demonym appears to be *Shreveporter*. An excerpt from the city's [council proceedings in 2007](http://www.shreveportla.gov/ccmin/2007/021cm2007.htm) reads:

> Councilman Shyne: Mr. Chairman, I saw a distinguished attorney just come in. I don’t know whether he wants to be recognized or not. That’s Attorney Jones. He’s a **distinguished Shreveporter**. We’re so happy to have you down gracing us with your presence.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any town name ending in "*...port*" where the denonym wasn't "*...porter*"

Comment: @PeterShor: That scheme works much better than, say, _Newburyportians_ – which would sound like what you'd get after you go on an all-fruit diet.

Answer (score 5):

If there was a consistent rule, then we would only have one demonym per region. That those for countries (which are probably the most firmly defined) include *Argentines*, *Argentineans* and *Argentinians* for people from Argentina, demonstrates that we do not have one demonym per region, and by extension that there isn't a consistent rule.

For extra fun, people can get very annoyed if you use the wrong one. Your best bet is to do a google search for likely candidates, but even then favour local references over sheer numbers. Also, don't assume that those from different places with the same name, use the same demonym.

Answer (score 1):

Oh great, I'm so glad I stumbled upon this. 3 years later... Tell you what, one person suggested you ask someone from Shreveport. I AM from Shreveport! Shreveporters don't actually refer to themselves at all, I notice. I would agree that "Shreveporter" is probably the best way to refer to us, but "Shreveportian" would probably be okay as well. Personally, I use the term "crazy" to refer to a person from Shreveport. But that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this. I grew up in Bossier City and agree with the other poster who said there actually is no demonym for folks who live in Shreveport or Bossier City for that matter. I think if anything we would say we are Louisianan but that actually doesn’t sound right either. We’d just say “I live in Bossier” or “I live in Shreveport”. I live in Dallas now and we are Dallasites. It seems weird now I grew up in place where we didn’t have names for ourselves!

I couldn’t wait to get out of Louisiana after college but I appreciate the culture and beauty of the state now. I love going back to visit family.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/429761)